# How to get data Mongo data using aggregate MongoDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose we have 10 collection, then we have to find the count on the basis of `tag_id`. For example, if `tag_id` contains 0 and 1, then we have to count all the data, as well as counting the data that don't have `tag_id`, or where `tag_id` is null. Then if it has unread : false then the output comes, count of all the unread.

Find the counts of tag_id and counts of unread when false.

```
 {
        "_id": ObjectId("5912c7240520df77f0c2c18a"),
        "email_id": "54",
        "unread": "false",
        "__v": NumberLong(0),
        "tag_id": ["0"

        ]
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("5912c71e0520df77f0c2c189"),
        "email_id": "55",
        "unread": "false",
        "__v": NumberLong(0),
        "tag_id": [
            "1"
        ]
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("5912c71d0520df77f0c2c186"),
        "email_id": "51",
        "unread": "false",
        "__v": NumberLong(0),
        "tag_id": [
            "2", "1"
        ]
    }
```

expected result:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "tag_id": "1",
        "count_email": 1,(count of email on the basis of tag_id)
        "unread": 9(count the unread on the basis of output of tag_id)
    }, {
        "tag_id": "3",
        "count_email": 45,
        "unread": 3
    }, {
        "tag_id": "2",
        "count_email": 5,
        "unread": 4
    }, {
        "id": null,
        "count_email": 52,
        "unread": 35
    }]
}
```

Comment: this is not clear, expected output does not correspond to the sample documents you provided. Can you update the expected output and add some details about what your trying to achieve ?

Comment: Mongo offers aggregations, map reduce, etc... but those operations in practice do not scale in a transactional system. If it's for analytics, then there are better suited data stores than mongo for that.

Comment: thanks . ok . will take care of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation pipeline.

The below query will `$unwind` the `tag_id` followed by `$group` to count `email` and `$cond` operator to count the `unread` email.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 {$unwind:{path:"$tag_id", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}}, 
 {$group:{
    _id:"$tag_id", 
     count_email:{$sum:1},
     unread:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$unread", "false"]}, 0, 1]}}
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks its works for me , i want to ask one thing more , if i have tag_id "id": null or don't have tag_id , i want the count for that
 {
        "id": null,
        "count_email": 52,
        "unread": 35
    }

Comment: can we find the same output without the use of $wind , because i am using mongo 3.0 version , and i have lots of projects using version 3.0 @veeram

Comment: You've may have to use map reduce. I think its worth creating separate question for 3.0 version.

Comment: can you tell me how to do with version 3.0

Comment: can you also check this , i already create a seprate question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015900/how-to-get-data-mongo-data-using-aggregate-mongodb-version-3-0/44017226?noredirect=1#comment75063383_44017226