# How to get Mongo data using aggregate MongoDB version 3.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Suppose we have 10 collections, then we have to find the count on the basis of tag_id. For example, if tag_id contains 0 and 1, then we have to count all the data, as well as counting the data that don't have tag_id, or where tag_id is null. Then if it has unread : false then the output comes, count of all the unread.

Find the counts of tag_id and counts of unread when false.

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId("5912c7240520df77f0c2c18a"),
        "email_id": "54",
        "unread": "false",
        "__v": NumberLong(0),
        "tag_id": ["0"

        ]
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("5912c71e0520df77f0c2c189"),
        "email_id": "55",
        "unread": "false",
        "__v": NumberLong(0),
        "tag_id": [
            "1"
        ]
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("5912c71d0520df77f0c2c186"),
        "email_id": "51",
        "unread": "false",
        "__v": NumberLong(0),
        "tag_id": [
            "2", "1"
        ]
    }
```

expected result:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "tag_id": "1",
        "count_email": 1,(count of email on the basis of tag_id)
        "unread": 9(count the unread on the basis of output of tag_id)
    }, {
        "tag_id": "3",
        "count_email": 45,
        "unread": 3
    }, {
        "tag_id": "2",
        "count_email": 5,
        "unread": 4
    }, {
        "id": null,
        "count_email": 52,
        "unread": 35
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code 
Refer - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

```
DB.aggregate([
                {$project:
                {
                    tag_id: '$tag_id',
                    unreadcount: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$unread', 'true' ] }, 1, 0 ] }
                }},
                { $group: {
                    _id: '$tag_id',
                    unread: { $sum: '$unreadcount'},
                }}
            ], function (err, results) {
                console.log(results);
            })
```

Comment: its gives me error  Unexpected token, expected , (70:24)
  68 | 
  69 |     req.email.aggregate([
> 70 |                 $project:
can you please fix this error so that i can use this

Comment: I thought you are getting these collections from DB. What is req.email? Can you paste the whole error message?

Comment: its a syntax error SyntaxError: /var/www/html/hr_system/src/controllers/fetch_email.js: Unexpected token, expected , (70:24)
  68 | 
  69 |     req.email.aggregate([
> 70 |                 $project:
     |                         ^
  71 |                 {
  72 |                     tag_id: '$tag_id',
  73 |                     unreadcount: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$unread', 'true' ] }, 1, 0 ] }

Comment: DB.aggregate([
                {$project:
                {
                    tag_id: '$tag_id',
                    unreadcount: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$unread', 'true' ] }, 1, 0 ] }
                }}
                { $group: {
                    _id: '$tag_id',
                    unread: { $sum: '$unreadcount'},
                }}
            ], function (err, results) {
                console.log(results);
            })

Comment: Observe the flower bracket before project, i missed it.

Comment: i find the result like this
 [ { _id: [ '2', '1' ], unread: 1 },
  { _id: [], unread: 0 },
  { _id: [ '2' ], unread: 0 },
  { _id: [ '2', '3' ], unread: 0 },
  { _id: null, unread: 0 } ]

Comment: can you see once , the expected result what i want

Comment: try tag_id: 1, inside project instead of tag_id: '$tag_id'. I'll get back if that doesn't work

Comment: but we can't use  unwind in version 3.0

Comment: i already have a solution for mongo 3.2 using $unwind ,but we cannot use $unwind in version 3.0 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914470/how-to-get-data-mongo-data-using-aggregate-mongodb

Comment: Oh, then the only way would be to take this result, run a for loop on that to get what you want

Comment: can we find using mongodb query like mapreduce orsomething like that

Comment: I don't think so